# Using 'height: 100%' and 'align-items: stretch' in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox with a direct child that is declared with `align-items: stretch`.

Inside this flexbox's direct child, I would like to have a div container that also uses its parent's full height (by setting `height: 100%`).

However, the div container won't stretch to 100% height of its parent, unless I also set `height: 100%` on the flexbox's direct child.

Is it kind of bug? Must I set the flexbox's direct child with `align-items: stretch` AND `height: 100%` to achieve what I want? It seem redundant to me.

Here is an example:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.flexbox-child {
  // height: 100%; uncommenting this will get it to work
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: blue;
}

.flexbox-grand-child {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flexbox-child">
    <div class="flexbox-grand-child">
      I want to be stretched till the bottom
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/FACkwsC2y65NcbOaceur?p=preview

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a complicated case.

Your `.flexbox-child` is only a flex item, but not a flex container. Therefore, `align-items: stretch`, which only applies to flex containers, is ignored.

Then, `.flexbox-grand-child` has a percentage [`height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property), which behaves like this:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to 'auto'.

The containing block is the flex item (`.flexbox-child`), which has no explicit height, and its height seems to depend on the content.

However, this dependency is only due to the new `min-height: auto`. But before taking `min-height` into account, the height of the flex item will be (due to the initial `align-self: stretch`) the height of the container, which is specified explicitly, ignoring the content.

Then, Firefox considers that the height of `.flexbox-child` does not depend on its contents, so `height` percentages in its children should work. And then your code works.

However, Chrome doesn't think so.

I'm not sure which one does it right. It doesn't help that `height` is only defined in the old CSS2.1 and in CSS basic box model, which is an inconsistent draft.

To be safe, better set the height of `.flexbox-child` explicitly. Or make it a flex container.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say you got that backwards, the bug is in FF. Percentage heights only should work when the height is "specified explicitly". Imho being a stretched flex items doesn't qualify. [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/woestijnrog/nbx92s5a/)

Comment: @woestijnrog Yes, but Firefox's behavior might still make sense. See my update.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Btw, what do you mean by "the new min-height: auto"?

Comment: @royv Previously, the initial value of `min-height` and `min-width` was `0`. However, the flexbox spec changes it to `auto`. `auto` behaves like `0` for most elements. However, for flex items with `overflow: visible`, it forces them to grow to cover their contents. See [Implied Minimum Size of Flex Items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)

Comment: I'm wondering if the spec has changed. Both FF(49) and Chrome(53) seem to have no issues making children of flex items be 100% height. But Safari (10) can't handle it and a specific height needs to be set on the flex item for children to stretch correctly.

Comment: @gman The spec has been reworded but I think this was already standard when I wrote this. Since the flex item is stretched, its height is considered definite (see [Definite and Indefinite Sizes](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#definite-sizes)), so the percentage should work. It was only a problem with Chrome's implementation, which has been fixed.

Comment: Except it's not fixed in Safari AFAIK :(  Works in FF, Works in Chrome, Does not work in Safari https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/Lz2yppab/

Answer (score 8):

When you create a flex container only the child elements become flex items. Descendants beyond the children do not become flex items and flex properties don't apply to them.

Simply apply `display: flex` to the flex item, which converts it into a flex container, as well. Then default flex properties like `align-items: stretch` will apply to the children (now flex items).

You wrote:

> I would like to have a div container that also uses its parent's full
>   height...

You don't need to use `height: 100%` or add `align-items: stretch` (it's a default rule). Simply add `display: flex` to `.flexbox-child`, and `.flexbox-grand-child` will expand the full available height.

Modified demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/n0Wt3x3CUr1ZfBD2RrGo?p=preview

---

**re: `height: 100% possible bug`**

With regard to the need to specify `height: 100%` on child elements, I don't see any bug here. Everything seems to conform to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property). Here's a complete explanation: [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)