# Equal-height nested flexbox columns

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container that has two columns, and the second column contains another flexbox container with two columns. I want the two nested columns to be the same height as the column that contains them, which is the same height as the other outer column.

Essentially, I want it to look like three equal-height columns with a gutter between them, like so:

[image: three equal-height columns]

I've made this work in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0z6h2gjd/1/) and [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzYXpK) by setting the height of the inner flexbox container to 100%.

The HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-col">
      <div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tortor metus, ultrices ut egestas eget, lacinia ut tellus. Duis consectetur velit ut aliquam convallis. Donec erat ex, interdum et justo in, varius pharetra nunc. Integer rutrum, ante nec gravida scelerisque, urna massa convallis enim, et tincidunt leo odio eget nisl. Ut et blandit velit, ac tristique massa. Integer leo mi, tincidunt in bibendum eu, blandit eget est. Cras convallis elit id urna convallis euismod.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-col">
      <div class="flex-container list-container">
        <div class="flex-col list">Content</div>
        <div class="flex-col list">Content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.box {
  background-color: blue;
}

.list-container {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-col.list {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -1em;
}

.flex-col {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

But here's the weird part: On Chrome, it seems to only work on these sites, and it doesn't work at all in Safari. If I open the JSFiddle or CodePen links in Safari, the two right columns appear **collapsed** to their content. Meanwhile, if I paste the same code into an HTML file and open it in **either** Chrome or Safari, the two right columns appear **stretched** to the viewport height. Both the file and the JSFiddle/CodePen links work fine in Firefox, however.

So my questions are:

1. What's going on here?
2. What's the best way to achieve the look I want, without setting a fixed height or sacrificing my gutters or my nesting?

Comment: Which version of safari?

Comment: @Dekel 9.0 (10601.1.56.2). Also, Chrome 53.0.2785.143 and Firefox Developer Edition 48.0a2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What's going on here?**

Your `.flex-col` is not a `flex-container`, it is just a flex-item. Then you use a `flex-container` inside that `flex-item`, which is working as expected, it fills the height of its own content.

---

**What's the best way to achieve the look I want, without setting a
    fixed height or sacrificing my gutters or my nesting?**

You need to make your `flex-item` a `flex-container` as well.

```css
.box {
  background-color: blue;
}
.flex-col.list {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -1em;
}
.flex-col {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.flex-col.flex-container {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-col">
      <div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tortor metus, ultrices ut egestas eget, lacinia ut tellus. Duis consectetur velit ut aliquam convallis. Donec erat ex, interdum et justo in, varius pharetra nunc. Integer rutrum, ante
        nec gravida scelerisque, urna massa convallis enim, et tincidunt leo odio eget nisl. Ut et blandit velit, ac tristique massa. Integer leo mi, tincidunt in bibendum eu, blandit eget est. Cras convallis elit id urna convallis euismod.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-col flex-container">
      <div class="flex-col list">Content</div>
      <div class="flex-col list">Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By "What's going on here?" I meant more "Why am I getting such inconsistent results?" (which I'm still curious about). But this works great, thanks! I know I'd tried that, but something else must have been messing it up. C'est la vie.

Comment: I think it was because you had `height: 100%` too. Read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33457515/4305494).